# NamedParameterJdbcTemplate very slow

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

I am using Spring NamedParameterJdbcTemplate in my search process, but when I get many results, its execution take several time and I don't know if there are a way to optimize it.
Here my code:

```
 NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jt = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(query);
 query = sb.toString();
 return jt.query(query, map, new MyRowMapper());
```

Have you any idea please?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things you can do
1. Why to create instance `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` every time when method is invoked? Create it once and pass previously created instance to the method.

```
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jt = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
```

keep `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` as class attribute and initialize it once.
2. What you are trying here?

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(query);
 query = sb.toString();
```

Pass `query` directly to `.query()` method if its of type `String`.
3. Inside `MyRowMapper`, make sure you are fetching and assigning only required fields in `mapRow` method. This might be affecting the execution time as `mapRow` is called once for every record in resultset.

Comment: I call this method only one time

Comment: @Mohamed: Then you must look at your rowMapper. If you are using only required fields in `mapRow` method then I dont think there is anything more you can do with your code.

Comment: @Mohamed: thats why its taking longer time? Is all 40 fields are necessary/used?

Comment: Yes, they are necessary. Is there any way to do that faster without using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate?

Comment: @Mohamed: AFAIK No. JCBC is the the fastest way to interact with database.